# Undeclared VB.NET Session Variable Type

Tags: vb.net, types, session-variables

What is the type of a VB.NET Session variable which has not been declared?

For example, let's say I had a session variable which had not been declared yet, say Session("foo").

If I were to check its type, what would it be?

Answer (score 2):

Session variables are of type `Object`.

An undeclared Session variable does not exist so you cannot check its type.

You should convert from type Object to your desired type when reading them (ensure you have Option Strict On):

```
Dim bar as string
bar = CType(Session("foo"), String)
```

Have a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which also includes guidelines for error conditions when reading

Comment: That's what I assumed. I did check its type using type name and it wrote "nothing" in the console.

Comment: The top half of your answer is helpful but the bottom half doesn't relate to my specific issue. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Just some additional info that I thought might be useful.